# Switching from Search API Database to Solr

Tags: search

i have a site which is already using **Search API database** and **Facets search** hosted on Acquia. The site main search (recipe search) is a  view with exposed filters to display search and similar content etc. And the site is in 2 languages ( EN and Arabic )

I need to implement spellcheck (did you mean) in the site and this module is only available for Solr.

I have no experience with Solr search. My question is how easy it will be to switch to Solr? Will i have to create different VIEW etc?

I have done a lot of theming, i am afraid of doing that all work again.

What is your expert opinion.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to switch search server for your search index. But I think your view can stay as configured now as it targets a index (which only will change server).

You will also need the module [Search API Spellcheck](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_spellcheck). Then add the "Search: Spellcheck" field to the header of your view. This will output the message “Did you mean "something" in the header if a suggestion is returned by Solr.

You will find the setting for which server your index should use under your index.

[image]

Comment: thank you @Pontus,  yes that what i was looking for. Any how i think i need to create a new server and new index. As i do not see any option to change server here. http://take.ms/dBsXI

Comment: It seems like i need to create the view again with the new index. http://take.ms/ddFzu . Am i right ?

Comment: You will find the setting for which server to use under your index. You should not need to create the view again.